# where to type code of Custom Validation

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to use custom validation in my form. I know how to write the code for it. But i don't know how i can make available my new "password" custom validation in VTYPE.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
password: function(val, field) {
if (field.initialPassField) {
var pwd = Ext.getCmp(field.initialPassField);
return (val == pwd.getValue());
}
return true;
},
passwordText: 'What are you doing?<br/>The passwords entered do not match!'
});
```

just tell me where i should write this "Password function" to achieve custom validation.

Thank you

Comment: Could not understanding what exactly you are asking about, but this link might help you out - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/adv-vtypes.html

Comment: i dont know how to add my custom vtype to the Inbuilt VType of sencha.                                                            where should i need to include password function?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provide any details of issue you are facing. That may help. You can create a separate js file for all custom vtypes and initialize this after ExtJS library code.

Updated my previous post with code example:

```
     Ext.onReady(function(){
       validationModule = function(){
          //here you can define your custom vtypes
       };

      validationModule();

    });
```

Best!!

Comment: im doing validation of 2 password fields. "http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/form/adv-vtypes.html". In this they have mentioned "// Add the additional 'advanced' VTypes" and i dont know how to add that inside "Ext.onReady(){...}". Hope now you understood my problem.

Comment: i got result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Include these config in your password field.

```
vtype: 'password'
```

or confirm me whether you are validating two password fileds, whether same passwords
entered should match?

Comment: Hi Surya, that config only im not able to find.it is showing only basic vtype config option like url,email.i have problem with "Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes" this line. i dont know where i should include my password function. and you are right. im validating 2 password fields.